# Is Rudin's PMA Outdated?

Tags: soft-question

I don't mean for this to sound like blasphemy, but I've heard this before. One of my analysis professors said something along the lines of "Baby Rudin is great if you need to learn how to write proofs." He went on to say that there were better, more modern texts for introductory analysis. His reasoning for why Baby Rudin is inferior to some of these books is that Rudin doesn't introduce topics such as normed linear spaces, Banach spaces, (a very good treatment of) measure, etc...

Comment: Papa Rudin introduces measures, normed spaces etc, and Grandpa Rudin goes in depth for functional analysis.

Comment: Introductory analysis and Banach spaces at the same time? I thought people studying introductory analysis had difficulties to grasp the idea of a sequence of just plain numbers...

Comment: @Sobi Yes, but my question was about Baby Rudin. Papa Rudin assumes all knowledge from Baby Rudin. There /are/ introductory texts which introduce the topics I mentioned.

Comment: As @Shashi pointed out, I see no reason why you would want to have all of those topics in an *introductory* real analysis book. I feel that Rudin did a great job in presenting analysis in three books, increasing gradually in difficulty.

Comment: The question is not for this site.

Comment: @YvesDaoust why is that? There are many questions similar to this.

Comment: @JDivision: try Mathematics Educators.

Answer (score 3):

Baby Rudin is an excellent book  for the first 1/2 courses in Analysis.
The topics you mention (Banach spaces, measure) do not came up usually in these courses or if they do they appear only in a mild manner.
So use the baby Rudin and do not worry about it.